# Chrome totally ignoring Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-chrome, apache2, cors

I am setting this with `htaccess`. I know it's being set properly because if I set another header:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin2: *
```

Then chrome does see this. As soon as I remove the 2 however, chrome just completely ignores it. If I make my file a PHP file and put this in it:

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

Then it works.

Here are the response headers as reported by Chrome of the *.htaccess* method which I need to work and which does not:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 00:13:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
ETag: "208f3-178a2-4f5c4f119cd34"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Here are the response headers as reported by Chrome from the PHP method which for some reason does work:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 00:13:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 23
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Again, I know the `htaccess` is setting the header, even if I go to an online service that checks reponse headers, I see this back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 00:18:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 29 Mar 2014 20:48:34 GMT
ETag: "208f3-178a2-4f5c4f119cd34"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 33393
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Comment: Try the syntax like this `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` and make sure to reload apache

Comment: No dice, still doesn't work :(

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: OS X, when I change the file name I'm trying to access to .txt it works, it doesn't work when it's .js,

Comment: Make sure `mod_headers` is enabled with Apache. Not sure if the command works for OS X but you can type `httpd -M` and see if headers_module is in the list, if not enable it.

Comment: it's enabled and I can set other headers and see them

Comment: Try setting the pre-flight OPTIONS after it, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST`, I once had a similar issue with `*` but I used my domain specifically like `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://yoursite.com"` and it worked even without the OPTIONS.

Comment: Sadly it still wont work in Chrome, for some reason safari reports the right headers...